# Bundling and Minification in MVC 6

Tags: bundling-and-minification, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

It looks like Bundling and Minification are no longer built into MVC 6 since there is no more `App_Start` and `Bundle.Config`.

Is this going to be the case after final release?

I'm guessing Grunt should be used since that seems to be baked into Visual Studio 2015.

**UPDATE**: It looks like Microsoft has switched to Gulp instead of Grunt in RC1.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Grunt is the recommended approach in ASP.NET 5 applications. There are no plans to build a system like the previous ASP.NET Bundling and Minification (Optimization) system.

Comment: That's super disappointing. Bundling and minification were fantastic in MVC. And the debugging behaviour was great. Grunt leaves a lot of work up to the developer, and everyone has their own technique. This feels like a step backwards.

Comment: Since this is a top Google result, thought it was a good place to update. This selected answer is no longer the case. The default way of bundling is now a VS extension, or on MAc/Linux a Nuget package exposed via command. See here: https://github.com/madskristensen/BundlerMinifier

Answer (score 10):

## Bundler & Minifier Extension

The default ASP.NET Core MVC 6 project template uses a Bundler & Minifier extension. The default template used to use Gulp which was far more powerful but it was deemed too complex for newbie developers who wanted something simple. You can read more about the switch away from Gulp and the reasoning [here](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/webdev/2016/06/22/notes-from-the-asp-net-community-standup-june-21-2016/) or read the documentation for the Bundler & Minifier extension [here](https://github.com/madskristensen/BundlerMinifier).

## WebPack, Gulp, Grunt, Brocoli, etc.

A much nicer and far more powerful method is to use [Gulp](http://gulpjs.com/), or any other task runner (There are others named Grunt, Brocoli etc. Gulp is apparently nicer to work with and newer than Grunt but also more popular than Brocoli). You can use the [ASP.NET MVC Boilerplate](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/6cf50a48-fc1e-4eaf-9e82-0b2a6705ca7d) project template to get a project with Gulp built in.

The new kid on the block is called WebPack which is according to Google about as popular as Gulp at the moment.

## ASP.NET MVC 5 Bundling and Minification and Smidge

The old bundling and minification in ASP.NET MVC 5 has been dropped but there is a project on GitHub to build it for MVC 6 called [Smidge](https://github.com/Shazwazza/Smidge).

Comment: It was just switched to Gulp in the RC1 version of Visual Studio.  It used to be Grunt in Beta.

Answer (score 2):

There is an extension for VS2015 to bundle and minify files, available here:
https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/9ec27da7-e24b-4d56-8064-fd7e88ac1c40

I have just used this an also created an html helper to render unbundled/unminified files in debug mode, helper available here:
https://bundlerminifierhelper.codeplex.com/

Using these you don't need to have any knowledge of gulp, task runners etc.

Answer (score 0):

SquishIt provides very similar capability and API to the MVC 5 bundling.  Actually it predated MVC bundling.  If you want to stay in the realm of .NET, ensure you can grow into more advanced bundling scenarios that will require tighter integration with contextual route attributes, avoid wasted time debugging serverside javascript that will fail silently when you make a minor typo or misplacement requiring you to eyeball all properties, and leverage the language that we know and love, then I'd recommend SquishIt.

Javascript has its place.  In my opinion this is not its place.

By using squishit you'll also decouple one less thing from the whim of the ASP.NET team.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, if you're looking for a very simple **lightweight** ASP.NET Core MVC6 Gulp template (instead of default .NET Core bundles), you can look at [my github](https://github.com/IvanSivak/ASP.NET-Core-MVC6-Gulp-Template) project.