# How to register bundles in ASP.NET Core 6?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-6.0

As the style of application startup has changed I can't find a way to register bundles of js files:

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);
    builder.Services.AddBundle    // this is no longer there
}
```

How to register bundles in ASP.NET Core 6 MVC?

Comment: I believe it is removed, see this SO for alternatives: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28455963/bundling-and-minification-in-mvc-6

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I add Bundle Config to Startup.cs for resources to use in Razor Views?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43018505/how-can-i-add-bundle-config-to-startup-cs-for-resources-to-use-in-razor-views)

Comment: As mentioned in the document https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/client-side/bundling-and-minification?view=aspnetcore-7.0#choose-a-bundling-and-minification-strategy,it was not provided by default any more,you have to try with third part tools